# How can I disable Top-level statements when using `dotnet new console`?

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli, .net-7.0

I created a C# project with the below command in VSCode and enabled Top-level statements automatically for this project.
How can I disable Top-level statements in Visual Studio Code for a C# project?

> dotnet new console --framework net7.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `--use-program-main`. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#console) for details.